# Iterate over an xpath (string) in R for data scraping

Tags: r, loops, for-loop, web-scraping

I've got a (pretty simple) code to download a table with data:

```
library(rvest)

link = "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/team/2442/statistics"
aguada = read_html(link)

stats = aguada %>% html_nodes("tbody")
stats = aguada %>% html_nodes(xpath="/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div[4]/table") %>% html_table()

my_df <- as.data.frame(stats)
```

And now I'm trying to do the same, but for the URLs for each player in the same table

```
for (i in 1:17){
  url_path="/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[i]/td[1]/a"
  jugador[i] = aguada %>% html_nodes(xpath=url_path)%>% html_attr("href")
}
```

I've tried the code above, and while it doesn't crash, it doesn't work as intended either. I want to create an array with the urls or something like that so I can then get the stats for each player easily. While we're at it, I'd like to know if, instead of doing `1:17` in the `for` and manually counting the players, there's a way to automate that too, so I can do something like `for i in 1:table_length`

Comment: My XPath is rusty but I'm fairly sure that a loop is unnecessary here, since XPath can address multiple elements. IIRC you should be able to simply remove the `[i]`. (EDIT: yes, that works)

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialise the vector `jugador` to be able to append the links to it. Also, when you create a path that invloves changing a character within the path, `paste` concatenates the strings with the number `i` to create the path, as shown below:

```
jugador <- vector()
for(i in 1:17){
  url_path <- paste("/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr[", i, "]/td[1]/a", sep = "")
  jugador[i] <- aguada %>% html_nodes(xpath=url_path)%>% html_attr("href")
}
```

Result:

```
> jugador
 [1] "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/person/15257?"  
 [2] "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/person/17101?"  
 [3] "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/person/17554?"  
 [4] "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/person/43225?"  
 [5] "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/person/262286?" 
 [6] "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/person/623893?" 
 [7] "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/person/725720?" 
 [8] "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/person/858052?" 
 [9] "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/person/1645559?"
[10] "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/person/1651515?"
[11] "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/person/1717089?"
[12] "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/person/1924883?"
[13] "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/person/1924884?"
[14] "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/person/1931124?"
[15] "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/person/1950388?"
[16] "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/person/1971299?"
[17] "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/person/1991297?"
```

Comment: Since you already know the size, it's much more efficient to initialize the vector with that length `jugador <- vector(length=17)` to allocate memory.

Answer (score 0):

Links in the last column. Without loop

```
library(tidyverse)
library(rvest)

page <-
  "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/team/2442/statistics" %>%
  read_html()

df <- page %>%
  html_table() %>%
  pluck(1) %>%
  janitor::clean_names() %>%
  mutate(link = page %>%
           html_elements("td a") %>%
           html_attr("href") %>%
           unique())


# A tibble: 17 x 21
   jugador          p     i pts_pr   pts as_pr    as ro_pr rd_pr rt_pr    rt bl_prom    bl re_pr    re min_pr tc_percent x2p_percent x3p_percent tl_percent link$value               
   <chr>        <int> <int>  <dbl> <int> <dbl> <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <int>   <dbl> <int> <dbl> <int>  <dbl>      <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>      <dbl> <chr>                    
 1 F. MEDINA       22     9    6     131   1.3    29   0.5   0.8   1.3    28     0       0   0.6    13   22         37          55.6        26.8       60   https://hosted.dcd.share~
 2 J. SANTISO      23    23   12     277   5.6   128   0.4   2.9   3.3    75     0       0   0.7    15   31         43.1        43.2        43         75   https://hosted.dcd.share~
 3 A. ZUVICH       17     1    8.2   139   0.7    11   2     2.9   4.9    83     0.5     8   1.1    19   15.9       59.8        67.1        16.7       76.5 https://hosted.dcd.share~
 4 A. YOUNG        15    14   12.5   187   1.3    20   0.4   3.3   3.7    55     0.5     7   0.6     9   30.5       36.2        41.9        32         78.8 https://hosted.dcd.share~
 5 E. VARGAS       23    23   16.1   370   1.9    44   3.5   8.4  11.9   273     1.6    37   1.1    25   30.3       53.3        53.5         0         62.6 https://hosted.dcd.share~
 6 L. PLANELLS     23     0    3.6    83   1.6    37   0.5   1.1   1.6    37     0.1     2   0.7    17   15.1       35.4        35.1        35.6       90   https://hosted.dcd.share~
 7 T. METZGER      11     9    6.8    75   0.6     7   1.7   3.3   5      55     0.4     4   0.5     5   23.1       37          44.2        28.9       40   https://hosted.dcd.share~
 8 L. SILVA        19     0    1.1    21   0.1     2   0.2   0.2   0.3     6     0.1     1   0       0    4         35          71.4        15.4      100   https://hosted.dcd.share~
 9 J. STOLL         2     0    0       0   0       0   0     0     0       0     0       0   0       0    1.2        0           0           0          0   https://hosted.dcd.share~
10 G. BRUN          4     0    0.8     3   0       0   0.3   0     0.3     1     0       0   0       0    0.6       50           0          50          0   https://hosted.dcd.share~
11 A. GENTILE       3     0    0       0   0       0   0.3   0.3   0.7     2     0       0   0       0    1          0           0           0          0   https://hosted.dcd.share~
12 L. CERMINATO    19     5    8.6   163   1.7    33   1.3   3.6   4.9    93     0.7    14   0.9    17   20.9       44.1        51.9        27.1       57.1 https://hosted.dcd.share~
13 J. ADAMS         8     8   16.6   133   1.9    15   1     2.5   3.5    28     0.3     2   1.9    15   28.9       46.2        53.9        26.7       81.8 https://hosted.dcd.share~
14 K. FULLER        5     5    4.6    23   1.8     9   0.6   0.6   1.2     6     0       0   0.4     2   20.1       17.1         0          28.6       83.3 https://hosted.dcd.share~
15 S. MAC           4     4   12.5    50   2       8   0     3     3      12     0.5     2   1.8     7   29.9       37.8        35.5        42.9       76.9 https://hosted.dcd.share~
16 O. JOHNSON      12    12   15.4   185   3.4    41   1     3.2   4.2    50     0.3     4   0.8     9   31.8       47.3        53.6        34.7       75   https://hosted.dcd.share~
17 G. SOLANO        2     2   15.5    31   6.5    13   0.5   5.5   6      12     0       0   1       2   32.4       41.4        55.6        18.2       71.4 https://hosted.dcd.share~
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside the string, `i` is just a regular character, and XPath doesn’t know it: it has no connection to the variables in your R session.

However, if you want to select *all* elements with a given XPath, you don’t need the index at all. That is, the following XPath expression works (I’ve simply removed the `[i]` part):

```
/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a
```

Here’s the corresponding ‘rvest’ code. Note that it uses no loop:

```
library(rvest)

link = "https://hosted.dcd.shared.geniussports.com/fubb/es/competition/34409/team/2442/statistics"
aguada = read_html(link)
jugador = aguada %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a/@href")
```

Or, alternatively:

```
jugador = aguada %>%
  html_nodes(xpath = "/html/body/div[1]/div[6]/div/div/div/div[4]/table/tbody/tr/td[1]/a") %>%
  html_attr("href")
```

Both return a vector of hyperrefs. The first solution has a slightly different return type (`xml_nodeset`) but for most purposes they will be similar.